# php file upload in Jquery Mobile

Tags: php, jquery-mobile, file-upload

Apologies if this is a duplicate question it just seems that every article i visit doesnt work for me.
I have a basic form which has two fields and a file.

```
<form action="make_announce.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" data-ajax="false">
<label>Enter Subject Line (500char max):
<input name="subject" type="text" id="subject" size="50"/></label>

<label>Announcement :
<textarea name="announce" cols="50" rows="10" id="announce"></textarea></label>

<label>Post Image (Leave Blank for NONE)<br>
<input type="hidden" name="MAX_FILE_SIZE" value="100000" />
<input type="file" name="image" /><br /></label>

<div align="center">
<input type="submit" name="Submit" value="OK" />
</div>
</form>
```

And my PHP File minus most of the variables.

```
if (!empty($_FILES["image"])) {
    $myFile = $_FILES["image"];

    if ($myFile["error"] !== UPLOAD_ERR_OK) {
        $sql="...
        mysqli_query($con,$sql);
    exit;
    }
    $name = preg_replace("/[^A-Z0-9._-]/i", "_", $myFile["name"]);
    $i = 0;
    $parts = pathinfo($name);
    while (file_exists(UPLOAD_DIR . $name)) {
        $i++;
        $name = $parts["filename"] . "-" . $i . "." . $parts["extension"];
    }
    $success = move_uploaded_file($myFile["tmp_name"],
        UPLOAD_DIR . $name);
    if (!$success) { 
    $sql="...
mysqli_query($con,$sql);
    exit;
    }
    else
    {
    chmod(UPLOAD_DIR . $name, 0644);
    $sql="...
    mysqli_query($con,$sql);
    exit;
    }


}
mysqli_close($con);
```

Although this may not be the best way to do this it does work fine on a basic php web page. however when i put it into a jquery mobile web page it again works but doesnt seem to be posting the file im uploading. even after finding lots of articles telling me to add the data-ajax="false" to my form.

Any help would be very much appreciated.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Turn off Ajax navigation using data-ajax="false" on your form definition because you can't upload files using Ajax.